# regex for single lower case word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex pattern that ensures the user puts in a single lower case word with only letters of the alphabet. Basically they are picking a subdomain. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you limiting your users to lower-case, presumably ASCII letters for subdomains? That's not all that's allowed in DNS.

Comment: What language? RegEx dialects have different features, so it's important to know. Java? .NET? Javascript? Perl? Python? Ruby? Something else?

Comment: Why not just force the input into lowercase afterwards. It seems unnecessary for an input field to fail validation because you don't allow uppercase characters.  Domains are case-insensitive, so however they write the sub-domain doesn't matter.  Also, hyphens are allowed in domain names.

Comment: you are right ... forget the lowercase. JS for the programing language and a-z

Comment: @Gumbo: Given that he's from Australia I'd guess he means the Australian alphabet, i.e. [z-ɐ].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The character class `[a-z]` describes one single character of the alphabet of lowercase letters `a`–`z`. If you want if an input does only contain characters of that class, use this:

```
^[a-z]+$
```

`^` and `$` mark the start and end of the string respectively. And the quantifier `+` allows one or more repetitions of the preceding expression.

Comment: Without any further detail, this is the first answer I would think of. If the OP would report if he needs to match any Unicode letter, the answer could be expanded.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Javascript Regex and Unicode... That would be crazy.

Answer (score 3):

^[a-z]+$  Will find one and only one lower-case word, with no spaces before or after the word.

Answer (score 0):

/^[a-z]+$/

make sure you aren't using 'i' after the last slash

/[a-z]+/

if you are searching for any words within the context

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find *all* occurrences of lowercase-only ASCII-char words, you can use

```
text.match(/\b[a-z]+\b/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZE3Xf9/3).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[a-z]+` - one or more (`+`) lowercase ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary

The `g` flag makes it extract all occurrences.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "123456789 Ticket number (CO2) text";
console.log(text.match(/\b[a-z]+\b/g));
```