# C# check to see if an input contains only lowercase letters a-z

Tags: string, punctuation

I'm stuck on a task of trying to print words that contain only lowercase letters a-z. I have already stripped out an inputted string if it contains any number 0-9 and if it contains an Uppercase letter:

```
    String[] textParts;
    textParts = text.Split(delimChars);
    for (int i = 0; i < textParts.Length; i++)  //adds s to words list and checks for capitals
    {
        String s = textParts[i];
        bool valid = true;

        foreach (char c in textParts[i])
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }

            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }

            if (char.IsPunctuation(c))
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (valid) pageIn.words.Add(s);
```

This is my code so far. The last part I'm trying to check to see if a word contains any punctuation (it's not working) is there an easier way I could do this and how could I get the last part of my code to work?

P.S. I'm not that comfortable with using Regex.

Many Thanks,
Ellie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434120/regex-for-single-lower-case-word#3434125 even though you're not comfortable, for the current case i believe regex is exactly what you would want.

Comment: I had an awful feeling it would be! If I use Regex then will it mean I do one check (is it lowercase?) and that's it? Anything else will be disregarded? (thank you)

Answer (score 3):

Without regex, you can use LINQ (might be less performant)

```
bool isOnlyLower = s.Count(c => Char.IsLower(c)) == s.Length;
```

Count will retrieve the number of char that are in lower in the following string. If it match the string's length, string is composed only of lowercase letters.

An alternative would be to check if there's any UpperCase :

```
bool isOnlyLower = !s.Any(c => Char.IsUpper(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex("^[a-z]+$");
if (!regex.IsMatch(input))
{
            // is't not only lower case letters, remove input
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, will have to do some reading up on Regex! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you think they are proper answers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
for (int i = 0; i < textParts.Length; i++)  //adds s to words list and checks for capitals
{
    String s = textParts[i];

    if(s.Equals(s.ToLower()))
    {
        // string is all lower
    }
}
```

Comment: (Sorry my English Writing skills aren't fantastic haha!)

I'm trying to create something that doesn't turn them into lowercase, they must be entered that way otherwise, GET RID.

Therefore if it contains a number remove the string, if it contains a Upper case letter, remove the string, therefore if it contains anything that isn't a lowercase letter, REMOVE THE STRING. 

I'm just having a problem checking to see if it contains any punctuation.