# Regular Expression Uninclusive Substring

Tags: regex

So I am given the following prompt for a regex I missed on an exam;
*Write a regular expression that matches any string over the 26 lower-case English letters that does not end in the string* **aa**. I am having an issue with the end part of the problem.

Comment: This could possibly be the most explicit worst question I have ever seen on here lol

Comment: Definitely not doing you any justice...but, I know how it is....the very top answer is prob your best (I would suggest actually learning LINQ though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209529/c-sharp-check-to-see-if-an-input-contains-only-lowercase-letters-a-z ;bc if this were a db indexes could be optimized for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a negative lookbehind to make sure that your string doesn't end in an aa.

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?<!aa)$
```

As per regex 101 this means: `Negative Lookbehind - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below(aa)`

Some examples:

- jkhasjkhasda <-- Does match because it only has one ending a
- jkhasjkhasdaa <-- Does NOT match because it ends in aa
- jaaaaaaaaaaah <-- Does match, aa is not at the end of the string

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for! Thanks a lot!